# hookbox for comet?

Tags: php, comet

i´ve read that one of the implementations of comet in your php application can be hookbox.

however, on their page i can´t download the stuff.

http://github.com/mcarter/hookbox

is the project dead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Downloads link in the menu may be empty, but the folder tree on the front page seems to contain all the files, you'll just have to manually copy'n'save them.

http://github.com/mcarter/hookbox